# creating a custom database in adobe business catalyst?

Tags: database, adobe, business-catalyst

I want to create a custom database within Adobe Business Catalyst. I have an Excel Spreadsheet with 1000's of rows of data that I want to upload.

Does anyone know how I can do this or where I can find instructions on how to do this as I cant seem to find anything anywhere???

Comment: Check out the [Adobe BC Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/community/business_catalyst). They would be your best bet for help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to use is the Web Apps module. You haven't told us what you want to do with this data but I assume that you simply want to render it on the page. Web apps will allow you to crate a custom field for every column in your spreadsheet and import that spreadsheet into it. It has a list view which creates an automatic link to a detail view. See the following link for more info -

http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/kb/add-custom-content-using-web.html

Comment: Ideally I wanted to use a database with phpmyadmin but realised I dont have access to this so I have been told to use WebApps to create the database.  The purpose of the database is I want to create a custom search facility where by customers can search by "Postcode" or "Suburb" and then a list of contact information appears for that location.

Comment: You can do that with web apps. They have a search facility that will create search form fields for every DB column you define. It's also integrated with Google Maps and will preform radius search.